# Predidcting svm model

Tags: r

data_list has different datasets.

```
daily_svm <- dt_list
weekly_svm <- dt_list

for(i in seq_along(dt_list)){
      tmp <- dt_list[[i]]
      train <- tmp[1:(nrow(tmpdat)-486), ]
      test <- tmp[506:686,]

      d_svm <- svm(load ~ daily, data = train,
                        type = "eps-regression")

      daily_svm[[i]] <- predict(d_svm, test)
```

I am running this model, but i get this error.
Error in daily_svm[[i]] <- predict(d_svm, test) : 
  replacement has length zero

Comment: Please show some example data.

Comment: dt_list <- v1, v2, v3

v1:
time  load  daily   week

v2:
time  load  daily  week

v3:
time  load  daily  week


i want to predict load for a particular time

Comment: the error states that your predict returns nothing. Try running it one line at a time, and look at your output from predict (or errors). Maybe you'll see the fix form this simple exercise. :-)